# Path not found when converting JSON files?

Tags: powershell

I am reformatting some JSON files, moving them to a new folder, and then searching them for some text. This script worked perfectly for a separate folder of JSON files. All I did was change the folder name, and now it can't find SOME of the files. I can't find anything different about these ones. Help!

```
$targetfolder = "C:\Users\jutrust\documents\MyFolder\*.json"
$files= get-childitem -path ($TargetFolder -replace '^"|"$') -recurse
foreach($file in $files)
    {
         $content = Get-Content $file -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
         $newFilePath = $file.FullName.Replace("MyFolder","MyNewFolder")
         ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $content -depth 100| Set-Content $newFilePath
         $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($newFilePath)
         $Line = Select-String -AllMatches -Path $Newfilepath -pattern "mytext"
```

Error looks like:

```
get-childitem : Could not find item C:\Users\jutrust\documents\MyFolder\File1_ name with (these + 
characters)_fg45f-fjh546-rt4de8-4rsgt7489.json.
+ $files= get-childitem -path ($TargetFolder -replace '^"|"$') -Recurse
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\jutrust...7489.json:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Edit for more info: That error is only for the first one for some reason. Every other error says:

```
Select-String : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\jutrust\documents\MyNewFolder\File2_ name with (different characters)_htg86ffgh6-gh8674-trh897rt.json' because it does not exist.
```

Which means it's not moving those files to the new folder. If I put one of the erring files as the $targetfolder directly, I get the more specific:

```
get-childitem : Illegal characters in path.
```

It is the direct, copied path. It exists with that name. Why would there be an issue?

Comment: The code looks incomplete, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It looks like you have chacaters in your path for which you need to use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`, so they won't be treated as wildcard characters (like the square brackets `[]`)
Change to `$targetfolder = "C:\Users\jutrust\documents\MyFolder"; $files= Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $targetFolder -Filter '*.json' -File -Recurse`. Also make sure the destination folder exists before you try to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using full file name, like below. Also better use string replace inside for loop

```
$targetfolder = "C:\Users\jutrust\documents\MyFolder"
$files= (Get-ChildItem "$targetfolder\*.json" -Recurse).FullName
foreach($file in $files)
    {
         $file=$file.Replace('^"|"$','')
         $content = Get-Content $file -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
         $newFilePath = $file.FullName.Replace("MyFolder","MyNewFolder")
         ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $content -depth 100| Set-Content $newFilePath
         $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($newFilePath)
         $Line = Select-String -AllMatches -Path $Newfilepath -pattern "mytext"
    }
```

Comment: This [1] totally ignores the `$targetFolder`, [2] uses `$file` sometimes as string, but sometimes not (where it is **not** a string, but a FileInfo or DirectoryInfo object), [3] doesn't check if the path in `$newFilePath` exists before writing to it etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not clear to me why you would want to convert a json file to object in `$content` and then re-convert that object back to json
without manipulating the data while you have it as object, the error message shows you have characters in the file name (most likely square brackets)
for which you need to use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`.

Your code could be improved like below:

```
$sourceFolder = 'C:\Users\jutrust\documents\MyFolder'
$targetFolder = 'C:\Users\jutrust\documents\MyNewFolder'
$files        = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourceFolder -Filter '*.json' -File -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $file.FullName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    # calculate the new destination path and create that subfolder if it doesn't already exist
    $destination = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath $file.DirectoryName.Substring($SourceFolder.Length)
    $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
    # construct the full destination by combining the target path with the actual filename
    $newFile = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $file.Name
    $content | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content -LiteralPath $newFile

    # now do whatever you need to do with that new file
    $Line = Select-String -AllMatches -LiteralPath $newFile -Pattern "mytext"

    # ...
}
```

Notes:

- `Join-Path` does not have a `-LiteralPath` parameter because it is purely a cmdlet that operates on strings without trying to resolve wildcard characters
- Using `.Replace()` on the path to obtain the destination path is tricky; better use Join-Path and the file's `DirectoryName` for that
- Always check/create the destination folder before you try to create or copy a file to that path
- Append switch `-File` on the Get-ChildItem cmdlet so it doesn't also return DirectoryInfo objects as well
- With **filesystem paths**, using the `New-Item` cmdlet with switch `-Force` either creates the folder or returns a reference object of an existing folder. Than means you do not have to explicitely test if the folder exists or not. Warning though. **DO NOT** use that technique on paths other than FileSystem paths (like for instance registry paths) because there you may risk losing all content of the existing container.

Comment: It seems I have just one more error. Whenever I try to select-string, I get the error that the file cannot be read and it could not be found. Based on some testing, I think the filenames are too long. If I try to manually "rename" them and save them as their _current name_, I get an error forcing me to shorten the name. So my question is, how could you incorporate a line to shorten the filename? Especially by n number of characters? I tried to insert `$newfile | rename-item -newname { $_.basename.substring(0,$_.basename.length-38) + $_.extension }` Said newname was null but only for _some_

Comment: Did you try configuring [Long Path Names](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/filr/filr-4/filr-desktop/t47bx2ogpfz7.html)?

Comment: I had not. However, this script needs to be able to be run by multiple users, some of whom do not have admin access to their computer or the technical skill to mess with group policy. I am not the tenant admin, so I can't set it for all computers either :(

Comment: @JuTrust `$_.basename.length-38` can return a negative value,,.

Comment: All of the filenames follow a basic pattern, including 38 characters that I don't need at the end (Date-time, unique ID, etc). I would get rid of them earlier but I have no control over the export process. I get the files the way they are